# Reading Content of Google DFP Display Tag

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I tried some JS code like this:

```
<script>
var tag = document.getElementById("my_navbar_ads");
var text = tag.innerHTML;
var n = text.search("site.image.tag.jpg");
if(n > 1){
tag.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

But then I noticed the DFP tags are in innerHTML, not the actually code of the display ad.

Is there any known way to read the actually content being displayed in a DFP (or any ad tag) so I can take some JS action (like hiding the DIV like above)?

Thanks!

Comment: can you edit dfp creatives for your task?

Comment: No.  It's not possible to edit the DFP vars or to even read most of them.  However, I did solve my problem by checking for content in the <iframe> element of the  <div> for the DFP display ad; and based on that, I could update the <div> when the <iframe> element was empty... problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research into this, and hacking away at googletags, I wanted to post back and mention that this cannot be done for cross-domain security reasons, so I cannot use JS to read the contents() of a different domain (I think I am saying this correctly).

Sorry to answer my own question; but seems appropriate after waiting 3 days without a reply, since I think I know why this cannot be done.